# javascript prototypical inheritance confusion

Tags: javascript

Below is a working example to show how the prototype of Javascript work. So from my understand is simply the customer instance inherited the prototype function of the Person.

```js
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
};
var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.getName());
Person.prototype.sayMyName = function () {
    alert('Hello, my name is ' + this.getName());
};
john.sayMyName();
var Customer = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
Customer.prototype = new Person();

var myCustomer = new Customer('Dream Inc.');
myCustomer.sayMyName();
Customer.prototype.setAmountDue = function (amountDue) {
    this.amountDue = amountDue;
};
Customer.prototype.getAmountDue = function () {
    return this.amountDue;
};
myCustomer.setAmountDue(2000);
alert(myCustomer.getAmountDue());
```

But one thing bug me is that why the author do a getAmountdue prototype function? it simply return this.amountDue.

Comment: Because he was educated as a Java programmer. It's a [getter method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

Comment: I think it's hard to say why the author did that. I recommend you to read this link http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not related to javascript prototypical inheritance.

To wrap the property into a function return could abstract the implementation.

For example, if your boss want you provide a decorated result of `this.amountDue`, you can just change the implementation of `getAmountDue` method.